# Fit a quadratic function of the form $f(t) = c_0 + c_1t + c_2t^2$ to the data points $(0,0), (1,9), (2,12), (3,29)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Fit a quadratic function of the form $f(t) = c_0 + c_1t + c_2t^2$ to the data points $(0,0), (1,9), (2,12), (3,29)$
>
> $c_0 = ?$
>
> $c_1 = ?$
>
> $c_2 = ?$

How can I do this? At first I thought I could do $x = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\\1&2\\1&3\end{bmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{bmatrix}0\\9\\12\\29\end{bmatrix}$ then I thought I could do $(x^Tx)^{-1} * y^T$ but for some reasson I only get a $c_0$ and $c_1$ and I need a $c_2$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no quadratic that passes through the given points. Do you mean a cubic? To fit a quadratic, we need only three data points. In this case, the fourth point is inconsistent with the other three points.

Comment: Are these points supposed to all lie on a quadratic curve, or is the quadratic function meant to approximate the data? If it is the former, please check to make sure you typed the correct points, because I am finding there is no quadratic that will interpolate these four points.

Comment: @Yusha: Is this the best least squares fit? See 5.4 #32: http://www.math.jhu.edu/~hhaosu/Teaching/0304FLA/20031031-Note-1.pdf

Comment: @Christian The points are correct.

Comment: Thanks @Moo I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $x$ matrix is not right. It has to be a 4 by 3 matrix, not 4 by 2. It has to be 
$$
 x = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4\\
1 & 3 & 9
\end{array}
\right] $$
So basically the rows of $x$ are of type $[ 1 \, x_j \, x^2_j]$ for a sample point $(x_j, y_j)$.

And then I think it's $c=(x^Tx)^{-1}x^Ty$ Where $c = [c_0, c_1, c_2]^T$ is the 3 by 1 column vector of unknown coefficients.